# Error when Validating HTML that PHP code printed

Tags: php, html

The line

```
print("<tr class='pointer' onclick=location.href='inventory.phpsetID=$setid&catID=$catID'>");
```

triggers errors when I validate my code:

```
Error: "=" in an unquoted attribute value. Probable causes: 
Attributes running together or a URL query string in an unquoted attribute value
```

[Link to validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.student.itn.liu.se%2F~simfo596%2Fsearch.php)

I don't know what triggers it, and don't understand the explanation of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to this:

```
print("<tr class='pointer' onclick=\"location.href='inventory.php?setID=$setid&catID=$catID'>\"");
```

The attribute **onlick**'s value should be inside quotes.

Comment: @SimonForsberg thanks, please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You need to concat the string with the variable using the PHP concatenation operator `.`:

```
print "<tr class='pointer' onclick=location.href='inventory.php?setID=" . $setid . "&catID=" . $catID "'>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your OnClick needs to be inside quotes, and the variables should be out of the Quotes.

```
print("<tr class='pointer' onclick=\"location.href='inventory.php?setID=" . $setid . "&catID=" . $catID . "'>\"");
```